# Appium Swipe( Pattern Functionality)

Tags: appium

I want to make a 'Z'in password pattern format . I have used the below apporach.but its taking three strokes or we can say three swipes in order to make. But i want to swipe whole path in a single stroke

```
     driver.swipe(532,270,770,249,2000);
     driver.swipe(770,249,535,493,2000);
     driver.swipe(535,493,775,492,2000);
     Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give a try ! 
I'm not sure if it does make sens, but let's try it may be it can be a good solution with the same logic

```
@Test
public void Swipe() {
new Actions(driver).swipe(532,270,770,249,2000).swipe(770,249,535,493,2000).swipe(535,493,775,492,2000).build().perform();
}
```

Comment: it was just a try. did u find any other solution ?

Comment: i just found an answer from another site     :"-----------------MultiTouchAction mta = new MultiTouchAction(driver);
TouchAction ta0 = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(200, 800, 1000).moveTo(200, 100).waitAction(100);
TouchAction ta1 = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(500, 800, 1000).moveTo(500, 1600).waitAction(100);
TouchAction ta2 = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(900, 800, 1000).moveTo(100, 800).waitAction(100);
mta.add(ta0).add(ta1).add(ta2).perform();

Comment: but this also not worked .......Plz let me know if u got result with same